# purpose of if (true)

Tags: c, if-statement

I've seen some code written like this:

```
if (true) {
... // do something
}
```

Why would you want to do something like this?  Is there any thing special about this structure?

THanks

Comment: Surprising, I know `while(true)`, but I am unable to understand `if(true)`

Comment: You could also write that as `{do something}`, so that true might be used as a poor toggle.

Comment: I've been kicked in the teeth once too many times not to reconsider using a properly defined `for` when a `while(true)` is a possibility :P It can be quite easy to make a mistake and cause an infinite loop and end up on this site wondering why.

Comment: It's now `while(true)`, it's `if(true)`. I can understand why we need to use `while(true)` (sometimes), but `if(true)`?

Comment: In Java `if(Boolean.TRUE)` is a nop

Answer (score 3):

Pretty much any modern compiler would just optimize this away. My guess is that someone put it there during development to let them easily remove a block of code (by changing `true` to `false`), and either forgot or didn't bother to remove it when they were done.

Answer (score 2):

This is one of many ways to segment out code during testing/development.  Many might debate whether or not it is good coding practice, but it can be a quick and handy way to compartmentalize code.  It is also a quick way to execute code that follows a complex conditional statement that you want to test.

Might be able to use it like this:

```
/* if (my_comlex_or_rare_conditional_case) then */
if (true) then
{
 lots of code here....
} /*End if */
```

Answer (score 1):

There have been times where I've added `true ||` or `false &&` inside a condition to force it to execute the branch and test the code - but only during development. The code you've posted doesn't need the if condition.