# What is the FICTIVE IF purpose?

Tags: .net

What is the possible purpose of this code: `if(1 == 1){...}`?

All I know untill now is what it's called "Fictive if".

Comment: In what context? Where did you find this?

Comment: I just was shown it in some code and was asked about it possible meaning.

Comment: I hope that there was some code between `{}`, and not *exactly* like you showed?

Comment: Duplicate of [purpose of if (true)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14514466/purpose-of-if-true).

Comment: Yes there was code inside brackets if(1==1){...}. I fixed it here too.

Comment: In high-level languages this code will optimized to `if(1){}` by compiler. (if it doesn't optimized by some compiler the it can be use for obfuscation) 

may be if you are interested in low level language this such instructions are equivalent to `nop` and use to create metamorphic version of a code.

Comment: Fictive means fictional, imaginary. The if itself is effectively a no-op, because there's no case where 1 doesn't equal 1 (zero not equaling zero may be a different story on some long-obsolete systems, but never mind that). Logically, the code is the same if you take out if (1==1){} and just leave whatever's between the curly braces. So, I can see somebody calling that if "fictional", if I squint hard enough.

Comment: You may as well do `{...}` if the scoping of the braces is desired.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the same as:

```
if (true)
{
}
```

It will always enter the block. That's what some lazy dev's do while "testing" a piece of code to force its execution into the `if` block. They sometimes forget to replace that for a real condition before taking the code to production.

Even worse is this:

```
if (true || originalCondition) {}
```

Avoid this kind of construction like the devil avoids the cross, for your own sake.

Comment: Hi @Renan. Why do they need to force its execution into the if block?

Comment: Suppose you have an application in production, and there are bug reports for a piece of code inside an `if` block. Suppose you can't get a debugger to run through that code because the condition always evaluates to `false`. Instead of setting the environment so that you can get inside the block, sometimes people change the code to force the condition to evaluate to `true`.

Comment: OK. Understood. For testing purpose. Thank You Renan!